# Using Global Variables in Function to Hide Columns

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I want:

User selects country on 'Country' sheet = this sets global variable 'CountryVariable' in Module1
Other Pages would show/hide columns based on this selection through a Worksheet_Activate() function calling the 'CountryVariable'. Code below.

I'm having a problem in creating the global variable and referencing this properly.

Can anyone help with this referencing?

Module 1:

```
'define the variable
    Public CountryVariable As String
```

Sheet("Country"):

```
'set variable CountryVariable on Module1 depneding on country selected, then move to next tab
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K11:L20")) Is Nothing Then
            If ActiveCell.Value = "UK" Then
            CountryVariable = "H:AG"
            End If
            If ActiveCell.Value = "Brazil" Then
            CountryVariable.Value = "AI:AZ"
            End If
            If ActiveCell.Value = "India" Then
            CountryVariable.Value = "BB:CB"
            End If
            If ActiveCell.Value = "Indonesia" Then
            CountryVariable.Value = "CD:DH"
            End If
            If ActiveCell.Value = "Turkey" Then
            CountryVariable.Value = "DJ:EE"
            End If
        Sheets("Team").Visible = True
        Sheets("Country").Visible = False
        Sheets("Team").Activate
        Sheets("Team").Select
        Sheets("Team").Range("K9").Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Example Tab:

```
 'on any sheet where this is present, the columns will be selected according to the chosen country
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call ResetButton1
    Call StartButton1
    ActiveSheet.Columns("H:FA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Columns(CountryVariable).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    End Sub
```

Comment: How are you ensuring CountryVariable has a valid value at all items? It will fail if not set and left as vbNullString

Comment: At first people will be directed the 'Country' tab to select their country, so this should not be an issue. The code throws an 'Invalid Qualifier' - slightly updated code sectionhere:

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K11:L20")) Is Nothing Then
            If ActiveCell.Value = "UK" Then
            Module1.CountryVariable = Columns("H:AG")
            End If
            If ActiveCell.Value = "Brazil" Then
            Module1.CountryVariable.Value = Columns("AI:AZ")
            End If

Comment: Also use  CountryVariable not CountryVariable.Value

Comment: Now showing a 'Type Mismatch' here: 
Module1.CountryVariable = Columns("H:AG")

Comment: It should be a string not a range i.e. CountryVariable = "H:AG"

Comment: Updated CountryVariable as a String and the following code:        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Kll:L16")) Is Nothing Then
            If ActiveCell.Value = "UK" Then
            Module1.CountryVariable = "H:AG"
            End If

Comment: but getting error "Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed...

Comment: Did you try my code? And on what line did you get that error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the whole thing but. There is an On Error Resume Next at present as if CountryVariable is left as its initial value of vbNullString it will error out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Selection.Count = 1 Then

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K11:L20")) Is Nothing Then

            Select Case Target
            Case "UK"
                CountryVariable = "H:AG"
            Case "Brazil"
                CountryVariable = "AI:AZ"
            Case "India"
                CountryVariable = "BB:CB"
            Case Is = "Indonesia"
                CountryVariable = "CD:DH"
            Case "Turkey"
                CountryVariable = "DJ:EE"
            End Select

            Sheets("Team").Visible = True
            Sheets("Country").Visible = False
            Sheets("Team").Activate
            Sheets("Team").Range("K9").Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call ResetButton1
    Call StartButton1
    ActiveSheet.Columns("H:FA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Columns(CountryVariable).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    On Error GoTo 0
    ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked a charm - thank you! I think the use of Case is self explanatory...."On error resume next" and "On Error GoTo 0" are linked together to set CountryVariable to 0 if it is null?

Comment: The on error was simply masking when CountryVariable isn't set i.e. when is vbNullString. This skips the error generated by attempting to hide a column("") ; which is clearly not valid. Remember to accept if answers question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745449/excel-categorize-table-by-column

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
Put HideColumnsTeam Sub in a separate Module.
Every time you are calling HideColumnsTeam sub you would pass column variables.

```
Sub HideColumnsTeam(ByVal CountryVariable As String)
    Call ResetButton1
    Call StartButton1
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Team").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Team").Columns("H:FA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Team").Columns(CountryVariable).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Team").Range("G9").Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim CountryVariable As String

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K11:L20")) Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveCell.Value = "UK" Then
        CountryVariable = "H:AG"
        End If
        If ActiveCell.Value = "Brazil" Then
        CountryVariable = "AI:AZ"
        End If
        If ActiveCell.Value = "India" Then
        CountryVariable = "BB:CB"
        End If
        If ActiveCell.Value = "Indonesia" Then
        CountryVariable = "CD:DH"
        End If
        If ActiveCell.Value = "Turkey" Then
        CountryVariable = "DJ:EE"
        End If
    If CountryVariable <> "" Then
        Sheets("Team").Visible = True
        Sheets("Country").Visible = False
        Call HideColumnsTeam(CountryVariable)
    End If
    Stop
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - could you help me understand? I want the function to work across multiple sheets where I would not be getting the input from. i.e. input comes from 'country' sheet; I need to store this variable somewhere, then on another sheet, I would need to call this variable again. From the above, it looks like the code calling the HideColumnsTeam function would need an input from the user each time...?

Comment: Sub HideColumnsTeam(ByVal CountryVariable As String):              ByVal CountryVariable As String - means that in order to call this Sub you would have to provide CountryVariable (string value). The question is how would you like to use constant variables: 1. would your macros be triggered one by one or 2. would you like to trigger macro later and use the same constant variable. In 1 case you can simply pass data from macro to macro using (ByVal). In 2 case you can put your variables into specific cell and later use those cells to update retrieve the value. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks - yes makes sense. I was hoping to save the variable and retrieve later without storing in a cell, hence wanted to use a global variable. The solution using 'Select Case' and error handling worked.