# Transform Excel Table Using Column Value as Category

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have an Excel table with data structured similar to:

```
Name                 Team        Role        Level   Laptop Monitor
Cheryle Parish       Archers     Programmer  Level2  Dell   2
Shandi Kime          Archers     Programmer  Level2  Dell   1
Edwardo Cookson      Archers     Programmer  Level1  HP     3
Voncile Deak         Archers     Programmer  Level2  HP     3
Boyd Cueva           Climbers    Tester      Level2  HP     2
Caryn Kear           Climbers    Programmer  Level2  Apple  1
Kirsten Hirt         Climbers    Tester      Level2  Apple  3
Ayana Mayfield       Climbers    Programmer  Level2  Dell   2
Venetta Embree       Archers     Programmer  Level2  Dell   3
Herb Obryan          Archers     Programmer  Level2  Dell   2
Isobel Steinmetz     Explorers   Tester      Level2  Apple  3
Valeri Eisen         Explorers   Programmer  Level1  Dell   1
Anibal Plumlee       Explorers   Programmer  Level1  Dell   3
Floretta Tunney      Explorers   Tester      Level1  Apple  1
Lilliana Klutts      Explorers   Programmer  Level1  HP     2
Gaston Custodio      Explorers   Programmer  Level1  HP     2
Jared  Phaneuf       Explorers   Manager     Level1  Dell   3
Melvin Monsivais     Climbers    Manager     Level2  HP     2
```

Is there any simple way to create a new table or tables where one of the columns represents the categories and the values in that column are the values in another column? For example, the above list if I chose "Role" the output table(s) are:

```
Programmer           Manager              Tester
Cheryle Parish       Jared  Phaneuf       Boyd Cueva           
Shandi Kime          Melvin Monsivais     Floretta Tunney      
Edwardo Cookson                           Isobel Steinmetz     
Voncile Deak                              Kirsten Hirt         
Caryn Kear
Ayana Mayfield
Venetta Embree       
Herb Obryan          
Valeri Eisen         
Anibal Plumlee       
Lilliana Klutts      
Gaston Custodio
```

The other entries in the source table are thrown away in the new tables. Ideally if there are any duplicates, the duplicates are ignored and the new tables only have unique values. A VBA solution would work, trying to avoid an external program.

We could choose any of the columns to be the category for classification in the new tables. For example, we could generate a lists of whoever has a particular laptop brand.

The closest I can come up with is to use pivot tables to generate something that would still need copy-and-paste type editing.

```
Manager     Jared  Phaneuf
            Melvin Monsivais
Programmer  Anibal Plumlee
            Ayana Mayfield
            Caryn Kear
            Cheryle Parish
            Edwardo Cookson
            Gaston Custodio
            Herb Obryan
            Lilliana Klutts
            Shandi Kime
            Valeri Eisen
            Venetta Embree
            Voncile Deak
Tester      Boyd Cueva
            Floretta Tunney
            Isobel Steinmetz
            Kirsten Hirt
```

I found this question which is similar [Excel Categorized table by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745449/excel-categorize-table-by-column), but the answer doesn't solve the above problem.

Comment: You may find pivot tables useful - not sure what data1/data2 represent... But also you may just use data ribbon > List > source drag over a2:a4 in your example - then repeat with another one for a5:a7 - see here https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/

Comment: Unfortunately I think you need to give a bigger data sample/set to give us a better view of the output. As far I understand you want to change the categorization from one column to another... (it looks like the Continent is your main category now and you want to re-categorize everything to Country, is this correct interpretation??). If that's the case, there are no easy way to re-categorize data....

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you want, but it might be a compromise that gets you close without forcing you to write VBA to pull this off, which is probably the only real way to get exactly what you are looking for.

You can create a pivot table here and put `Role` in the Columns, `Name` in the Rows, and `Name` again in the `Values` and you will get a `1` if a name falls in a particular `Role`. You can swap `Role` out easily using the pivot table with `Level` or `Laptop` or whatever.

You may be able to build some formulas that feed from this pivot table to get exactly what you need, but again... that will be quite a bit more effort:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm reaching the same conclusion that a pivot table may have to be the simplest solution unless there is some VBA magic.

Comment: There's some VBA magic, but if you aren't comfortable with VBA it would be a beast to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done using formulas. Might be too much work and even harder to maintain, but these two links should be a good start (sorry have no time to provide full answer):

- [get unique list](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list)
- [subset matching rows](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/09/28/extract-all-rows-from-a-range-that-meet-criteria-in-one-column-in-excel/)